# Is Titus 3:9 evidence that Matthew’s Gospel genealogy was in circulation & criticized for including Jeconiah?

Tags: matthew, prophecy, genealogy, titus

The Controversy associated with Jesus’ genealogy in Matthew 1:12 involves God’s Curse on Jeconiah’s descendants from Jeremiah 22:24-30.

**Matthew 1:12 sets up a genealogy for Jesus’ Davidic kingship over Israel through “Jeconiah”. | But the author of Matthew’s genealogy may have forgotten the prophecy of Jeremiah 22 verses 24 & 30.**

[24] “As I live, says the Lord, though Coniah the son of Jehoiakim, king of Judah, be a signet on My right hand, from there I will remove you.” ( חַי־אָנִי֘ נְאֻם־יְהֹוָה֒ כִּ֣י אִם־יִֽהְיֶ֞ה כָּנְיָ֚הוּ בֶן־יְהֽוֹיָקִים֙ מֶ֣לֶךְ יְהוּדָ֔ה חוֹתָ֖ם עַל־יַ֣ד יְמִינִ֑י כִּ֥י מִשָּׁ֖ם אֶתְּקֶֽנְךָּ )

[30] “So said YHVH: Inscribe this man childless, a man who will not prosper in his days, for no man of his seed shall prosper, sitting on the throne of David or ruling anymore in Judah.” ( כֹּ֣ה | אָמַ֣ר יְהֹוָ֗ה כִּתְב֞וּ אֶת־הָאִ֚ישׁ הַזֶּה֙ עֲרִירִ֔י גֶּ֖בֶר לֹֽא־יִצְלַ֣ח בְּיָמָ֑יו כִּי֩ לֹ֨א יִצְלַ֜ח מִזַּרְע֗וֹ אִישׁ ישֵׁב֙ עַל־כִּסֵּ֣א דָוִ֔ד וּמוֹשֵׁ֥ל ע֖וֹד בִּֽיהוּדָֽה )

**Perhaps Matthew’s Gospel had been in circulation prior to the publication of [Titus 3:9] when the early churches had begun questioning prophetic problems associated with Jesus’ ancestry from Jeconiah in relation to inheriting David’s throne.**

- [9] But avoid foolish controversies and genealogies and arguments and quarrels about the law, because these are unprofitable and useless.

**Is Titus 3:9 evidence that Matthew’s Gospel genealogy was in circulation & criticized for including Jeconiah?**

Comment: Jesus of Nazareth was not descended of Jeconiah. He was not Jeconiah's 'seed' by natural generation. Only by adoption by Joseph. Jesus was not a 'descendant' of Jeconiah. But he inherited the throne rights (which had passed through several generations, but could not be accessed because of the curse), by adoption, but not by natural generation. The premise of this question is false. Matthew's genealogy correctly traces the _crown rights_. But those rights could not be accessed, until God arranged _a way of placing one on the throne of David_ but without a curse.

Comment: I'm surprised that this would be the first line of inquiry as to the meaning of this verse - surely since Matthew and Luke's genealogies for Jesus are different, this would be the more obvious first candidate. The other key factor in play here is different assumptions about the dating of each of the gospels, especially in comparison to Titus.

Comment: *the early churches had begun questioning prophetic problems associated with Jesus’ ancestry from Jeconiah* - Neither the New Testament (outside the two genealogies), nor early patristic writings, even bother mentioning Jeconiah (except perhaps when quoting the two genealogies).

Comment: @Lucian - "except perhaps when quoting the two genealogies" as you stated - This leads to foolish controversies (like Jesus' Davidic genealogy from Jeconiah) which Titus 3:9 seems to be highlighting.

Comment: @חִידָה: In case you haven't noticed, neither Titus, nor any of Paul's other letters, and not even the rest of the New Testament, apart from two verses in Matthew, bother mentioning Jeconiah; as such. it's highly doubtful that he mattered very much to the early Christians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some read too much into Jer 22:30 than is either necessary or required.

**Royal Descendant**

It is true that Jeconiah/Jehoiachin never had another decendant literally sit on the throne of David - he was succeeded by his uncle, Zedekiah; but none of his sons or grandsons we ever crowned king.

**Biological Descendants**

Both Matt 1 and 1 Chron 3:17 list the progeny of Jeconiah/Jehoiachin.

- 1 Chron 3:17-19 - The descendants of Jeconiah the captive: Shealtiel his son, Malchiram, Pedaiah, Shenazzar, Jekamiah, Hoshama, and Nedabiah.  The sons of Pedaiah: Zerubbabel and Shimei.

While Zerubbabel was one of the leaders who returned from Babylon, he never made any attempt to be king of Israel or Judah.

The central point of the Matt 1 genealogy is to show that Messiah was from the correct line of David but was never crowned king of the earthly kingdom of Judah.

However, Jesus was the king of the Kingdom of God/Heaven as per Rev 11:15-18.

**Titus 3:9**

The prohibition by Paul to avoid pointless genealogies is a salutary warning just as relevant today as it was when it was written almost 2000 years ago.  There are numerous companies making huge prophets out of people spending huge money tracing ancestry.  The only ancestry that is important in the NT is whether the person is a "son of God" (John 11:52, 1 John 3;10, Rom 8:14, Gal 4:6, Phil 2:15, etc) or a son of the devil (Acts 13:10, 1 John 3:8, John 8:44)

Comment: Please know that your words are more than a check mark ✅. I have written your response in my own copy of the NT to reference when addressing such foolish controversies. May God continue to use your research to bless others in their Torah studies.

Comment: @חִידָה - many thanks for your kind and generous encouragement. It is an honor to be of service.